# How to convert char* to TCHAR in Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

For example,

```cpp
const char* bytes = "somemultibytecharacter一些宽字符";
size_t n = strlen(bytes);
```

How to convert `bytes` to `FString` or `TCHAR*` in Unreal Engine C++ code?

I know I can convert with [std::mbstowcs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbstowcs) or [MultiByteToWideChar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar), but I'm trying to find a UE4 alternative.

Comment: Use the `TEXT` macro, `TCHAR* bytes = TEXT("somemultibytecharacter一些宽字符");`

Comment: @George You are right if `bytes` is raw literal, but in my case `bytes` is actually an external variable which I cannot control. http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `FString(int32 InCount, const CharType* InSrc)`.

Usage:

```cpp
const char* bytes = "somemultibytecharacter一些宽字符";
size_t n = strlen(bytes);
const FString& Str = FString(n, bytes);
const TCHAR* Text = *Str;
```

Note, in my copy of Unreal Engine 4, `TCHAR` is `wchar_t`:

```cpp
typedef wchar_t  WIDECHAR;
typedef WIDECHAR TCHAR
```